# running python in init.d script

Tags: python, ubuntu, init.d

To use python to be executed automatically when instance(AWS) is rebooted,
I wrote script inside of `/etc/init.d` like below

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/botrun

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting example"
    python /home/ubuntu/botrun/run.py &
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping example"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "use"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

after doing `chmod +x` to botrun, and `update-rc.d botrun defaults`
I checked whether it runs python `.py` file but it doesn't work.
Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: Did you check your syslog?

Comment: Did it throw any tracebacks?

Comment: @Mandraenke how can I check?

Comment: @Adam no tracebacks. I accessed through ssh

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/341970 that is how you handle `init.d` errors

Comment: @adam faster than I was

Comment: @Adam I found this `/etc/init.d/botrunt: 7: /etc/init.d/botrun: python: not found`

Comment: use `which python` to find the absolute path to the python executable and then use that in your script instead of just `python`

Comment: @Adam I figured the thing and another error occurs